# K-Means on temporal dataset

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, k-means, pca, temporal-tables

I have a temporal dataset(1000000x70) consisting of info about the activities of 20 subjects. I need to apply subsampling to the dataset as it has more than a million rows.  How to select a set of observations of each subject ideally from it? Later, I need to apply PCA and K-means on it.  Kindly help me with the steps to be followed. I'm working in MATLAB.

Comment: Your question is a little vague. Maybe you could take a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Or if your question is only related to machine learning and not how to implement it then you might want to ask it [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: My question is only related to machine learning. I have 70 columns and a million rows of the temporal dataset related to 20 subjects.  I need to do subsampling on the dataset, to be more specific, I need to  I need to choose wisely the best possible fixed number of observations(which will be then used to create the machine learning model) of each of the subjects. I need to know how to do that.

Comment: Then this question doesn't belong here. You will have more luck asking it [there](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). Especially it the answer below is not what you are looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really clear on what you're looking for. If you just want to subsample a matrix on matlab, here is a way to do it:

```matlab
myData;                      % 70 x 1000000  data
nbDataPts = size(myData, 2); % Get the number of points in the data

subsampleRatio = 0.1;        % Ratio of data you want to keep
nbSamples = round(subsampleRatio * nbDataPts);  % How many points to keep
sampleIdx = round(linspace(1, nbDataPts, nbSamples)); % Evenly space indices of the points to keep

sampledData = myData(:, sampleIdx);  % Sampling data
```

Then if you want to apply PCA and K means I suggest you take a look at the relevant documentation:

- [PCA](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/stats/pca.html)
- [K means](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/stats/kmeans.html)

Try to work with it, and open a new question if a specific problem arises.